# How to make the iframe height dynamic according to the content and avoiding vertical scrolls in iframe?

Tags: iframe, dynamic, height

I tried to search on this topic but couldn't find anything suitable working. Could you guys please suggest a method?
I have an iframe that needs to display the php content. Now,some php content is short some is pretty long and i want my iframe to acquire the height according to the content it contains.Thats pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Javascript in :

```
<script>
  function DynamicIframe(obj) {
    obj.style.height = obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
</script>
```

Declaration iframe like this:

```
<iframe src="..." frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="DynamicIframe(this)" />
```